# Negotiation with "DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256" cipher is failing

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am testing my web server with some ciphers and observed that some of the ciphers like DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256 are failing to negotiate with client with **handshake failure** error.

Here is the response on the client:

$ curl -k https://10.67.192.141:4443/a.html --ciphers DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
curl: (35) error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure

Am I doing anything wrong?
It works when I use different cipher like "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"

Comment: Your server likely does not support the cipher since it has no DSA certificate. Unfortunately nothing is known about your server, i.e. what kind of certificates it has installed and what ciphers are configured.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich,
I also tried to user OpenSSL S_SERVER but getting same behavior.

Comment: Just using a different server implementation does not magically turn your certificate into a DSA certificate and does not magically make ciphers available.

Comment: If an ECDHE-ECDSA ciphersuite works then the server has an ECDSA (aka ECC) certificate-and-key, and ECDSA/ECC is not DSA-aka-DSS (the then-SSL suites were named DSS back before 1998 when FIPS186 only covered one algorithm DSA; SSH similarly has algorithm name ssh-dss instead of ssh-dsa, but OpenSSH has filename id_dsa -- and nowadays severely deprecates it). (@SteffenUllrich) PLUS for DHE-DSS the server must _also_ have FFDHE _parameters_; some do this by default but some require you specify them, so you need to be very specific about the server.

Comment: There is very little need to use DSS anymore. Not sure what you want to achieve, but basically the use is deprecated and often support is limited to 2048 bit keys (where we would like at least 3072 bits for RSA and DSS).